# Is there a way to control PC by laptop keyboard without online?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, sharing

I am looking for a way to control my PC with a laptop.
Currently, there are one laptop that can be online and one PC that is in an offline environment.
The two are connected with a 2 Port USB Switch and controlled with a wired keyboard and a wireless mouse.

I know it's a wise way to stay in this state, but I want to make free place for my desk to put my arms on and I want to remove the wired keyboard I am using.

I've been looking for several solutions like Microsoft Garage Mouse without Borders, but most of them were controlling laptops and PCs connected to each other online(They are should on same network environment).

Is there a way to control PC by loptob keyboard without online?

Comment: Define online? If they are not connected together how can they communicate.  You could potentially use a wireless keyboard which can work with multiple PCs (like some logitec devices using Flow) https://www.howtogeek.com/317962/how-to-use-logitech-flow-for-mice-and-keyboards-across-multiple-computers/

Comment: Mouse without Borders and Synergy should both work fine offline, all they need is a LAN connection

Comment: Alternatively, if both devices have bluetooth and the laptop is running Linux, [you can have it act as a bluetooth keyboard for the PC](https://github.com/xenogenesi/hidclient), though that takes a non-negligible amount of technical setup.